# How do I perform the following sql query with an ActionLink MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

Is it possible to click on a actionlink name and have it retrieve the associated records much like the sql statement below?  CustomerName html link --> goes to the index of the customer detail view only retrieving the records associated with the customer name (CustomerNameID).

```
SELECT dbo.CustomerName.CustomerNameName, dbo.CustomerDetail.CustomerNameID
FROM dbo.CustomerDetail INNER JOIN
     dbo.CustomerName ON dbo.CustomerDetail.CustomerNameID = dbo.Cust
```

Model: CustomerName

```
 public partial class CustomerName
    {
        public CustomerName()
        {
            this.CustomerDetails = new HashSet<CustomerDetail>();
            this.CustomerEquipments = new HashSet<CustomerEquipment>();
            this.CustomerHealthChecks = new HashSet<CustomerHealthCheck>();
        }

        public int CustomerNameID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CustomerHealthCheckID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CustomerEquipmentID { get; set; }
        public int MasterLicNum { get; set; }
        public string CustomerNameName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Active { get; set; }

        public virtual CustomerDetail CustomerDetail { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CustomerDetail> CustomerDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CustomerEquipment> CustomerEquipments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CustomerHealthCheck> CustomerHealthChecks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model:CustomerDetail

```
public partial class CustomerDetail
    {
        public CustomerDetail()
        {
            this.CustomerNotes = new HashSet<CustomerNote>();
        }

        public int CustomerDetailID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerNameID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public int CustomerPriorityID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerStatusHealthID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> EquipmentID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CustomerHealthCheckID { get; set; }
        public int LREngineerID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerEngineerID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

        public virtual CustomerEngineer CustomerEngineer { get; set; }
        public virtual CustomerName CustomerName { get; set; }
        public virtual CustomerPriority CustomerPriority { get; set; }
        public virtual CustomerStatusHealth CustomerStatusHealth { get; set; }
        public virtual LREngineer LREngineer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CustomerNote> CustomerNotes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
return View(CustomerName.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.CustomerNameName.ToString(), "Index", "CustomerDetail", new {ID = item.CustomerNameID }, null)
```

Route:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "CustomerName", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

I rebuilt my controller to clean it up.  It is the standard out of the box controller at the moment.
CustomerNameController Index():

```
// GET: CustomerName
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? CustomerNameID = null)
{
    return View(await db.CustomerNames.ToListAsync());
}

// GET: CustomerName/Details/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    CustomerName customerName = await db.CustomerNames.FindAsync(id);
    if (customerName == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(customerName);
}
```

CustomerDetailController Index():

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            var customerDetails = db.CustomerDetails.Include(c => c.CustomerEngineer).Include(c => c.CustomerName).Include(c => c.CustomerPriority).Include(c => c.CustomerStatusHealth).Include(c => c.LREngineer);
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
             var CustomerDetails = from s in db.CustomerDetails
                           select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                CustomerDetails = CustomerDetails.Where(s => s.Description.Contains(searchString));
            }
            switch (sortOrder)
           {
                case "name_desc":
                    CustomerDetails = CustomerDetails.OrderByDescending(s => s.CustomerNameID);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    CustomerDetails = CustomerDetails.OrderBy(s => s.DateUpdated);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    CustomerDetails = CustomerDetails.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateUpdated);
                    break;
                default:  // Name ascending 
                    CustomerDetails = CustomerDetails.OrderBy(s => s.CustomerNameID);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 15;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            //return View(await customerDetails.ToListAsync());
            return View(CustomerDetails.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Of course. Show the `Index()` method of `CustomerDetailController` (although I suspect you really need another method (say `Details(int ID)` to return a view showing the details)

Comment: Your `@Html.ActionLink()` is calling the `Index()` method of `CustomerDetailController` and passing it the `CustomerNameID`, yet the method expects paraeters `string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page`. Hard to understand this because of your confusing naming conventions but I suspect it should be `@Html.ActionLink(item.CustomerNameName.ToString(), "Detail", "CustomerName", new {ID = item.CustomerNameID }, ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple yet I failed to grasp it.  After running the program numerous times I noticed that the CustomerName/Index ID was being passed but the CustomerDetail/Index was failing to pick it up and filter the results.  I added the following code and it finally worked.  Thanks all for the help.

```
        // GET: CustomerDetail
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int CustomerNameID)
    {

        IQueryable<CustomerDetail> CustomerDetail = db.CustomerDetails
           .Where(c => c.CustomerNameID == CustomerNameID)
           .OrderBy(d => d.CustomerNameID)
           .Include(d => d.CustomerName);


        return View(await CustomerDetail.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

```
SELECT dbo.CustomerName.CustomerNameName, dbo.CustomerDetail.CustomerNameID
FROM dbo.CustomerDetail INNER JOIN
     dbo.CustomerName ON dbo.CustomerDetail.CustomerNameID = dbo.Cust
```

In LINQ:

```
var query = from detail in CustomerDetails
            //from name in CustomerNames.Where(r=>r.CustomerDetail == detail)
            from name in CustomerNames.Where(r=>r.CustomerNameID == detail.CustomerNameID)
            select new {CustomerName = name.CustomerName, CustomerNameId = detail.CustomerNameId}
```

**OFF**

If you want to display details on the same page, modify `Index` action. Create a model which will contain customers list and details object.

Check input parameter for null, if so return only customers list. If parameter is not null, return customers list with customer details.

```
public ViewResult Index(int? customerId = null)
{
    if(cusomerId == null)
    {
        return new IndexModel {Customers = customersList};
    }
    else
    {
        return new IndexModel {Customers = customersList, Details = getDetailsById(customerId)};
    }
}
```

Model Example:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public List<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
    public CustomerDetails Details {get;set;}
}
```

ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.CustomerNameName.ToString(), "Index", "CustomerDetail", new {customerId = item.CustomerNameID }, null)
```